# Use RadioButtons without RadioGroup?

Tags: android, xml

Can i use RadioButtons without a RadioGroup? If not then please explain why? I am programming a layout for an android app in xml.

Comment: If you don't want them to be **mutually exclusive**, then **yes** you can.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Answer is **Yes**. you can used RadioButton without RadioGroup.But if you are using RadioButton without RadioGroup then you have doing Programming for that to make it perfect way.

I have posted both the Example so you can better understand.

#### RadioButton without RadioGroup Example :

Let's say this is your layout with RadioGroup.

**layout.xml:**

```
<RadioButton 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/radBtnMM"
/>
<RadioButton 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/radBtnInch"
/>
```

To handle it selection the java code is below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radBtnInch);
    rb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radBtnMM);
    rb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    return true;
  }
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
      if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.radBtnInch) {
        rb2.setChecked(false);
      }
      if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.radBtnMM) {
        rb1.setChecked(false);
      }
    }
  }
```

#### RadioButton with RadioGroup Example :

Let's say you used RadioGroup like below.

```
<RadioGroup
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="90dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
   android:weightSum="1"
   android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

   <RadioButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="55dp"
      android:text="Male"
      android:id="@+id/radioButton"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:checked="false"
      android:textSize="25dp" />

   <RadioButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Female"
      android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:checked="false"
      android:textSize="25dp"
      android:layout_weight="0.13" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="New Button"
   android:id="@+id/button"
   android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

then you can simple handle selection and display selection in Toast like this,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
   private RadioButton radioSexButton;
   private Button btnDisplay;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      radioSexGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

      btnDisplay=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

      btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            int selectedId=radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            radioSexButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,radioSexButton.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
      });
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

`RadioButton` can be used without `RadioGroup`. `RadioGroup` is just a helper wrapper around `RadioButton`s to give you some capabilities like if you select a `RadioButton,` all other `RadioButton`s in that group will automatically be deselected. If you do without `RadioGroup` then you have to implement those functionalities yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Harshad's answer is good. But it doesn't work fully. I just modified his code a little bit.

```
@Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
      if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.radBtnInch) {
        rb2.setChecked(!isChecked);
      }
      if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.radBtnMM) {
        rb1.setChecked(!isChecked);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: if isChecked is true !isChecked is alltime false

Answer (score 0):

I've created solution below to handle this as I've created layout using ConstraintLayout and was not able to handle RadioButtons by RadioGroup.
The CustomRadioGroup is handling isChecked state by itself and you are able to set check state by calling setButtonAsChecked method.

I've added the HashMap as you might need to handle values each RadioButton represents.

```
class CustomRadioGroup<ID, RB : RadioButton> constructor(
    private val radioButtons: HashMap<ID, RB>,
    private val listener: ((ID) -> Unit)?) {

    init {
        for (id in radioButtons.keys) {
            radioButtons[id]?.setOnCheckedChangeListener(CheckListener(id))
        }
    }

    fun setButtonAsChecked(checkedButtonId: ID) {
        for (id in radioButtons.keys) {
            val radioButton = radioButtons[id]
            radioButton?.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
            radioButton?.isChecked = id == checkedButtonId
            radioButton?.setOnCheckedChangeListener(CheckListener(id))
        }
    }

    private inner class CheckListener(private val id: ID) : CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

        override fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton?, isChecked: Boolean) {
            listener?.invoke(id)
            setButtonAsChecked(id)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
                val checkBoxes = arrayOfNulls<RadioButton>(7)
                checkBoxes[0] = findViewById(R.id.chip1)
                checkBoxes[1] = findViewById(R.id.chip2)
                checkBoxes[2] = findViewById(R.id.chip3)
                checkBoxes[3] = findViewById(R.id.chip4)
                checkBoxes[4] = findViewById(R.id.chip5)
                checkBoxes[5] = findViewById(R.id.chip6)
                checkBoxes[6] = findViewById(R.id.chip7)

                for (i in 0..6) {
                    checkBoxes[i]?.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                        for (ii in 0..6) {
                            checkBoxes[ii]?.isChecked = false

                        }
                        checkBoxes[i]!!.isChecked = true
                    })
                }
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Consider adding a description to this piece of code so it's easiest to understand, also the OP mention he/she is using XML for the layout so probably this code alone is not that helpful